# Want to make it obvious that I can reverse reference by related_name in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

### My Environment

- IDE: VSCode
- Extensions of VSCode

  - Python
  - Pylance
  - Ruff
  - Python Type Hint
  - isort
  - djLint
  - Django
  - Black Formatter

### What's my problem

I am working on a quiz submission site with Django.

I created a `models.py` file for a quiz and a user as follows:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Quiz(models.model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posted_quizzes"
    )
    correct_answer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The above code adds the property `posted_quizzes` to the user class due to Django's `related_name` reverse querying functionality.

This is a very useful function, but it is not obvious just by looking at the User class, even though it is a property of the User class.

I often define new methods, forgetting that they are accessible via `related_name`.

Is there any way that properties added via `related_name` can be seen directly from the User class?

### What I tried

I tried adding directly as an unimplemented property as follows:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    @property
    def posted_quizzes(self):
        """
        defined by related_name of Quiz model

        posts the user posted
        """
        pass

class Quiz(models.model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posted_quizzes"
    )
    correct_answer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

This method is good in that it does not change the migration, but it is too much code.

Comment: What is stopping you from accessing the quizzes with `some_user_object.posted_quizzes.all()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably add an annotation:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    posted_quizzes: QuerySet
```

> Is there any way that properties added via related_name can be seen directly from the User class?

The professional edition of PyCharm (JetBrains) for example has an extra module to have more "understanding" about Django, it thus can inspect the Django models, and can automatically perform autocompletion.